# Multiple filters in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, next.js

I'm trying to do a multiple filter in javascript. It consists in 5 filters: search input, maxYear, minYear and if a string contains one item of an array of strings (x2).

I started doing this:

```js
let entries = formattedJsonResults;

if (search) {
  const filtered = entries.filter(entry =>
    entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );
  entries = filtered;
} else if (minYear) {
  const filtered = entries.filter(entry =>
    Number(entry.date.slice(0, 4)) >= minYear.getFullYear()
  );
  entries = filtered;
} else if (maxYear) {
  const filtered = entries.filter(entry =>
    Number(entry.date.slice(0, 4)) <= maxYear.getFullYear()
  );
  entries = filtered;
}
```

But later I realized that they are not compatible. Eg, if search exists, I'll never access to the minYear filter.

Can someone help me please? thanks

Comment: What is `search`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Use individual if-statements, rather than an if-else. Also, use the previously filtered result for the next filter.

```js
const entries = formattedJsonResults;
let filtered = entries;

// Filter by search term
if (search) {
  filtered = filtered.filter(entry =>
    entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );
}

// Filter by minimum year
if (minYear) {
  filtered = filtered.filter(entry =>
    Number(entry.date.slice(0, 4)) >= minYear.getFullYear()
  );
}

// Filter by maximum year
if (maxYear) {
  filtered = filtered.filter(entry =>
    Number(entry.date.slice(0, 4)) <= maxYear.getFullYear()
  );
}

// Filter by annotations
if (annotations) {
  filtered = filtered.filter(entry =>
    annotations.includes(entry.annotation)
  );
}

console.log(filtered); // After filtering 1x to 4x
```

Comment: Thanks! and now I added another filter that consists in the following: I have one parameter called annotations, which is a string of words separated with commas (eg: video, image, GPS), and also a filter where I select one or many of them. How could I filter my array to know if the selected entry has at least one of the selected filters? thanks

Comment: @Emiliano either `'video, image, GPS'.split(/,\s*/g).includes(str)` or `'video, image, GPS'.includes(str)`. I updated the response above to include the latter usage.